# Air Canada luggage allowance when flying from Europe to USA

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, air-canada

I'm having a very hard time understanding the luggage policy of Air Canada as it applies to my journey.

I read on its site that, according to some parameters (miles, airports, fidelity...) you have different types of luggage allowed by your flight ticket.

Assuming I'll fly from Milan to Frankfurt via Lufthansa (on the same Air Canada itinerary), from Frankfurt to Toronto and from Toronto to Los Angeles. What is my luggage allowance on this ticket? Do I have a cabin bag, a hold bag?

I don't find any useful information on its site or in its policy, perhaps because English is not my first language but I'm having difficulty planning for my luggage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find more information at https://www.aircanada.com/us/en/aco/home/plan/baggage.html

Of course depending on your type of ticket, your free allowance may change. If you are in Basic economy (yes United/Lufthansa/AC do sell Basic Economy even in International sectors sadly), you may not be allowed any free allowance except a personal item.

You may find specifics of your allowance at https://www.aircanada.com/us/en/aco/home/plan/baggage/checked.html or by clicking on 'My Bookings' tab at https://www.aircanada.com/us/en/aco/home.html#/home:

If you have already done this step, the best information will be available by reaching out to them. More information at https://www.aircanada.com/us/en/aco/home/fly/customer-support.html